# Android programatically getting device default phone number from contacts

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, phone-number

I got name and contact id from android "my" contact by using this method

```
                 String[] columnNames = new String[] { Phone._ID,
                        Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };

                Cursor c = LoginActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, columnNames,
                        null, null, null);
                int count = c.getCount();
                boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
                int position = c.getPosition();
                if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
                        contact_id = c.getString(0);
                        namee = c.getString(1);


                    }
                }
```

How to get phone number of the device too?

Comment: You need to ask for another column in your `columnNames` array. Then do `c.getString(2);` Though i recommend using actual fieldnames rather than indexes.

Comment: Do you want the number saved in ME profile or sim number ?

Comment: @Doomsknight error getting when added another column

Comment: DId you add `Phone.NUMBER` to `ColumnNames`?

Comment: @RahulPatil i want the number saved in me contact not sim number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Use Following code to get "Me" contact.

```
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle arguments) {
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
            Uri.withAppendedPath( ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY),
            ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

            //Don't select anything here null will return all available fields

            null,
            null,                   
            null);
}
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    ArrayList<String> DataArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                //here where you get your data and its type
        TypeName=cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS);//this will give you field name
        Data=cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.NUMBER);//this will give you field data

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
}
private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS  ,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA3,

    };

    int ADDRESS = 0;
    int NUMBER = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        int contactIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID);
        int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
        int photoIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.PHOTO_ID);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String idContact = cursor.getString(contactIdIdx);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
            String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

And in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: i dont want all contacts just the me contact

Comment: I'm sorry I have not got it right. you just want your phone number?

Comment: yeah from myself contact

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
String[] columnNames = new String[] { Phone._ID,
                            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };

        Cursor c = LoginActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, columnNames,
                            null, null, null);
         int count = c.getCount();
         boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
         int position = c.getPosition();
         if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
         for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
             contact_id = c.getString(0);
             namee = c.getString(1); 
      if(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                  Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+ " = ?",new String[] { contact_id  }, null);


              while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                  String noo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }
          }
     }
                    }
```

Comment: whats cr and pcurgetcolumnindex?

Comment: pCur  is use to get phone No using contact_id.

Comment: forgate to add dot between pCur and getcolumnindex, ok change now

Comment: have u tried this . i getting Illegalstateexception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71174/discussion-between-sinceksaji-and-lokesh).

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way of doing it

1) call the intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
if(intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

2) Implement onActivityResult

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE) {

                uriContact = data.getData();

                // replaceAll("\\D", "") : Remove everything that is not a digit
                String number = retrieveContactNumber();
                if (Connectivity.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                    if (number != null) {
                        String contact_number = number.replaceAll("\\D", "");
                    } 
                }
            }
      }
}
```

3) implement retrieveContactNumber()

```
private String retrieveContactNumber() {

        String contactNumber = null;

        // getting contacts ID
        Cursor cursorID = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {
            contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        }

        cursorID.close();

        // Using the contact ID to get contact phone number
        Cursor cursorPhone = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                new String[]{contactID},
                null);

        if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
            contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        cursorPhone.close();

        return contactNumber;
    }
```

4) Enjoy :)

Comment: its for all contacts i need me contact only without selecting

Comment: myself contact in sdk >14 android phones

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` and there is column called `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` using which you may get contact number.

Have a look this code

```
public ArrayList<String> getContactList(){

         ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();

            Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            String[] columns    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

            Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, null, null, null);

            int _nameIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int _numberIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

            people.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String name   = people.getString(_nameIndex);
                String number = people.getString(_numberIndex);
                list.add(name+" :"+number);
                // Do work...
            } while (people.moveToNext());

        return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
            String[] columnNames = new String[] { Phone._ID,
                    Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };

            Cursor c = LoginActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, columnNames,
                    null, null, null);
            int count = c.getCount();
            boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
            int position = c.getPosition();
            if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
                    contact_id = c.getString(0);
                    name = c.getString(1);
                    number= c.getString(2);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Add this in the manifest. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />